Unicity of SDE solution
I'm studying a particular class of SDE (reference here) and in the proof of the uniqueness of the solution (theorem 6) I don't understand a passage concerning stochastic integrals. The setting is:

$(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space with a complete and right continuous filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)$, and $B_t$ is the standard brownian motion taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and adapted to $\mathcal{F}_t$;
$\sigma:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ satisfies, for every $T>0$, lipschitz condition
$$
|\sigma(t,x)-\sigma(t,y)|\leq L_T|x-y|\quad \mathbb{P}-a.s.\quad\forall\,t\in[0,T]\quad \forall\,x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n;
$$
$X$ is a $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted process that solves a certain SDE (which I think is not necessary to specify) and is square integrable, specifically for every $t\geq 0$
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t|X_s|^2\,ds\right]<\infty;
$$
$h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is $C^2$, concave and s.t. $|\nabla^2 h|_\infty<\infty$.

In the computations at a certain point the quantity
$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t\nabla h(X_s)\sigma(s,X_s)\,dB_s\right]
$
vanishes, and my interpretation is that it is satisfied the condition
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t|\nabla h(X_s)\sigma(s,X_s)|^2\,ds\right]<\infty
$$
But using the hypothesis I only get, for some $C>0$ (depending on $T$ and $|\nabla^2h|_\infty$) and for $t\in[0,T]$
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t|\nabla h(X_s)\sigma(s,X_s)|^2\,ds\right]\leq C\left(1+t+\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t|X_s|^4\,ds\right]\right)
$$
since $\nabla h$ has (at most) linear growth and $\sigma$ is lipschitz, and I can't go on from here.
Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!
